# how to strip customized missing value pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataset with a customized missing values which is the character `\?` but a cell with the missing value also contains whitespaces with inconsistent number of space characters. As in my example picture, at row 11, It could have 3 spaces, or 4 spaces.

So my idea is to apply the `str.strip()` function for each cell to identify it as the missing values and drop it, but it still is not recognized as missing values.

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv('full_name', header=None, na_values=['?'])
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip() if x.dtype== 'object' else x)
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True, how='any')
df.head(20)]
```

what is an efficient way to solve this?

Comment: no, I mean the apply works. I can remove the whitespaces. but the problem is after I clean the data this way. the dataframe does not recognize these cells as the missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropna` drops NaN values. Since your NaNs are actually `?`, you could `replace` them with NaN and use `dropna`:

```
df = df.replace('?', np.nan).dropna()
```

`mask` them and use `dropna`:

```
df = df.mask(df.eq('?')).dropna()
```

or simply filter those rows out and only select rows without any `?`:

```
df = df[df.ne('?').all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Can I further ask the different use cases of using apply, mask, and where? I'm reading the documents here and a bit confused. thanks. seems to me like there are doing the same job

Comment: @tmo `mask` lets you replace values where the condition is True, but in our case here, we didn't replace it, but left it as NaN instead; `where` does the same job but in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test': [1,2, '    ? ', ' ?   ']})
df[~df['test'].str.contains('\?', na=False)]
```